# Reproduce connection reset c#

Tags: c#, sockets, ioexception

How can I reproduce the following exception for testing purposes:

```
    Exception: System.IO.IOException
    Message: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

    Nested Exception

    Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException Message: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    Source: System
    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

It intermittently occurs, I have written some code that uses the retry pattern however I'd like to be able to test my fix works.

Comment: simply force and exception `throw new System.IO.IOException("Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.");`

Comment: @Franck You're a star!